# Text document classification with AWS Machine Learning

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, document-classification

I've been looking at using AWS Machine Learning to implement a categorizer for my project. I have something on the order of 40,000 documents that have a several text-only features. For example: Name (< 200 chars) and Description (potentially hundreds / thousands of words).

In a nutshell, I'm looking to assign categories (0 or more) to each document based on it's content.

I've read through the AWS ML tutorial and checked out a few other sources but the available material seems to deal with feature fields that are numeric, boolean, datetime, or otherwise non-textual.

Is AWS Machine Learning capable of performing multi-class categorization on documents based primarily (or possibly only) on text fields? And if so, is there any reference material available for this particular avenue?

Answer (score -1):

Mainly, you don`t need "text fields", first you have to create a vector space model (VTM) from your corpus (texts), than you can weight your VTM with tf-idf, and you can use numeric field.

Are you sure that do you want to apply AWS ML to train a corpus with only 40.000 documents?